# Beautiful soup extract text between span tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<span id="priceblock_dealprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 33,990.00 </span>
```

I need to extract the numbers 33,990.00 from the above html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use `selenium`? It's so unnecessary. Only use `selenium` if the page is JavaScript rendered. Otherwise use the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<span id="priceblock_dealprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 33,990.00 </span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
text = soup.select_one('span.a-color-price').text.strip()
```

Output:

```
33,990.00
```

Answer (score 1):

With beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

content = '''<span id="priceblock_dealprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 33,990.00 </span>'''

soup = bs(content,'html5lib')
print(soup.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good job for [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(URL)

delay = 30  # seconds
WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'priceblock_dealprice')))
print("Page is ready!")

text = browser.find_element_by_id("priceblock_dealprice").text
```

Comment: Is using selenium not killing a fly with a shotgun? ;)